# Print Soap Body data using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have a following XML . I need to store whole body xml from the Soap request in a variable .

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cre="http://www.code.com/abc/V1/createCase">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/a.xsd"></wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/30.xsd" wsu:Id="id-14">
      <cre:createCase>
         <cre:Request>
            <cre:ServiceAttributesGrp>
               <cre:MinorVer>?</cre:MinorVer>
            </cre:ServiceAttributesGrp>
            <cre:CreateCaseReqGrp>
               <cre:Language>English</cre:Language>
               <cre:CustFirstNm>Issue</cre:CustFirstNm>
               <cre:CustLastNm>Detection</cre:CustLastNm>
               <cre:AddlDynInfoGrp>
                  <cre:AddlDynInfo>
                           <cre:FieldNm>TM3</cre:FieldNm>
                           <cre:FieldVal></cre:FieldVal>
                  </cre:AddlDynInfo>
                  <cre:AddlDynInfo>
                           <cre:FieldNm>PM417</cre:FieldNm>
                           <cre:FieldVal>Not Defined</cre:FieldVal>
                  </cre:AddlDynInfo>
               </cre:AddlDynInfoGrp>
               <cre:CreateCriteriasGrp>
                  <cre:CreateCriterias>
                     <cre:CriteriaNm>CriticalReqDtlValidationReqd</cre:CriteriaNm>
                  </cre:CreateCriterias>
               </cre:CreateCriteriasGrp>
            </cre:CreateCaseReqGrp>
         </cre:Request>
      </cre:createCase>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As of now I am trying to print in the following manner , but I am unable to :

```
ns = {'cre': 'http://www.americanexpress.com/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1/createCase' , 'soapenv':'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'}
     tree = etree.parse(template_xml)
     root = tree.getroot()
     for bodytag in root.xpath('soapenv:Body/cre:createCase',namespaces=ns):
       print bodytag
       datalevel = etree.XPathEvaluator(bodytag,namespaces=ns)
       print datalevel('cre:createCase').text()
```

I just need to print the createCase part .

Comment: where is `ns`  in here?

Comment: createCase has child elements, do you want to print the text of each element under it?

Comment: I want to print the whole xml of 
 <cre:createCase>
         <cre:Request>......
        </cre:Request>
   </cre:createCase>

Comment: I answered your request. Let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dumped your xml into variable `root`, here is how you can get that piece of XML:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
createCase=root.find('.//cre:createCase',namespaces=root.nsmap)
print ET.tostring(createCase, pretty_print=True)
```

prints this:

```
<cre:createCase xmlns:cre="http://www.code.com/abc/V1/createCase" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/30.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <cre:Request>
        <cre:ServiceAttributesGrp>
           <cre:MinorVer>?</cre:MinorVer>
        </cre:ServiceAttributesGrp>
        <cre:CreateCaseReqGrp>
           <cre:Language>English</cre:Language>
           <cre:CustFirstNm>Issue</cre:CustFirstNm>
           <cre:CustLastNm>Detection</cre:CustLastNm>
           <cre:AddlDynInfoGrp>
              <cre:AddlDynInfo>
                       <cre:FieldNm>TM3</cre:FieldNm>
                       <cre:FieldVal/>
              </cre:AddlDynInfo>
              <cre:AddlDynInfo>
                       <cre:FieldNm>PM417</cre:FieldNm>
                       <cre:FieldVal>Not Defined</cre:FieldVal>
              </cre:AddlDynInfo>
           </cre:AddlDynInfoGrp>
           <cre:CreateCriteriasGrp>
              <cre:CreateCriterias>
                 <cre:CriteriaNm>CriticalReqDtlValidationReqd</cre:CriteriaNm>
              </cre:CreateCriterias>
           </cre:CreateCriteriasGrp>
        </cre:CreateCaseReqGrp>
     </cre:Request>
  </cre:createCase>
```

EDIT:
OP was using an older version of python/lxml that did not take namespaces, the right code was:

```
createCase=etree.tostring(root.find('.//{http://www.code.com/abc/V1/createCase}createCase'))
print etree.tostring(createCase, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: @IshuGupta should be `root` in your code (tree may also work)

Comment: @salparadise..I am getting this error:

    createCase=tree.find('.//cre:createCase',namespaces=ns)
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @IshuGupta try it with `createCase=root.find('.//cre:createCase',namespaces=root.nsmap)` and if that doesn't work post a `type(tree)` and `type(root)`

Comment: That also did not work for me : Here are the types:

`posting type tree :  <type 'lxml.etree._ElementTree'>`
`posting type root :  <type 'lxml.etree._Element'>`

Comment: @IshuGupta The last one should have worked then. did you get the same error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72641/discussion-between-ishu-gupta-and-salparadise).